# Can default value of argument depend on another argument in typescript

Tags: typescript

For example, can I do the following:

```js
const execute = (a, c = a.b) => {
// some logic
}
```

c is the parameter whose default value I want to set, and the default value depends on the first argument.

Can I also do the reverse? (I guess not?)

```js
const execute = (c = a.b, a) => {
// some logic
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is no problem. It can even infer the type of `c` from `a.b`.

```
const execute1 = (a: { b: number}, c = a.b) => {
    console.log(a, c)
}
execute1({ b: 123 }) // { b: 123 }, 123
```

However, the second one won't work. When `c` is being assigned, `a` has not been assigned yet. So the compiler complains at you:

```
// Error: Parameter 'c' cannot reference identifier 'a' declared after it.(2373)
const execute2 = (c: number = a.b, a: { b: number }) => {
    console.log(a, c)
}
```

[Typescript Playground with code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDzsArlOBGGBeGAKAQwC4YBvGAIxLBQFsK4AnAXwBoZgcYCA6CgShwA+MgCgYEjuAggANnB6yQAc0Ltg-Uc1GJkaTHnJUYGAEwBmGM0EB6G2UokzltiYujRdmAFFGjEIwkAAoEjAS0cOiMMADkwDEcBGBgILCMcABmTHBgwHAwAJYAJjlQBRkFTLEECSXAsqFwRdwZUYVQPHgWAOzmmqCQsLqo6KZceMDUdAzRuLwU7MQOxjT0VdbCYpJSkHIKSqoE6praQA)